# При установки сайта на modx на OpenServer выходит ошибка

Tags: modx, openserver, установка

Я пробовал установить сайт, который работал на удалённом хостинге, на локальный OpenServer выходит ошибка:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function parseProperties() on null in C:\OSPanel\domains\armaturnik.ru\core\model\modx\modelement.class.php:524 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\armaturnik.ru\core\model\modx\modx.class.php(1607): modElement->getProperties() #1 C:\OSPanel\domains\armaturnik.ru\core\model\modx\modx.class.php(538): modX->invokeEvent('OnMODXInit', Array) #2 C:\OSPanel\domains\armaturnik.ru\index.php(53): modX->initialize('web') #3 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\armaturnik.ru\core\model\modx\modelement.class.php on line 524

Перенастроил конфиги под этот локальный сайт: БД,DOCUMENT_ROOT (C:/OSPanel/domains/armaturnik.ru/), http_host и т.д., но ничего не выходит. В OpenServer запускал как в php 5.6 и в php 7.0 — одно и то же.

Как мне быть?

Answer (score 1):

1. Пропишите новый путь к core в этих файлах:
   /config.core.php
   /manager/config.core.php
   /connectors/config.core.php
   /core/config/config.inc.php
2. Очистите полностью /core/cache/

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.